# Trouble connecting to other PC's TCP socket server

Tags: java, networking

Me and my friend are working on online game project and for beginning we use TCP connection made by java. What do I have to do to successfuly make my friends client connect to my server? On local host it works perfectly. What are the reqiurements for this?

Comment: Don't forget to add the correct rules if you and your friend got a firewall

Comment: Change the IP address to the other machine and make sure there is no firewall or routers in the way.

Comment: what do you mean "coorrect rules"?

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue What do you exactly mean by "add the correct rules"? Can you tell us what exactly is the solution if the firewall is blocking our connection?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I guess that Nedas is using a router to connect to internet. What should he do?

Comment: You need to configure your firewall and router to allow the port you want to access to be accessible. How you do that depends on the firewall and router you have and is not related to Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You could write an anwser explaining what exactly shoud Nedas do :)

Comment: He should do is look up how to configure his router and firewall software/hardware. I didn't put this as an answer because its impossible to be very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your firewall allows connections from remote hosts to your computer on the port you are hosting the game on.  If you friend is connecting to your computer from another location you will most likely need to add a firewall rule to your router.

Comment: within your firewall program there are rules.  What OS are you using?  What kind of firewall/router for your network are you using? If you are using windows then you can go to the security center in the control panel and add firewall rules there to allow for those ports that your friend would need to connect to.  For your network router/firewall you would need to forward or map a port to your computer for someone outside of your network to connect to it.